# Sharing factories across rspec specs in a DRY way

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, factory-bot

So I have some model specs like this:

```
describe 'something' do
  it 'another thing' do
    a_model = FactoryGirl.create(:a_model)
    another = FactoryGirl.create(:another)
    #some code using a_model and another 
  end
end
```

Then, I have another model spec with:

```
describe 'something else' do
  it 'another test' do
    a_model = FactoryGirl.create(:a_model)
    another = FactoryGirl.create(:another)
    #different code using a_model and another 
  end
end
```

My question is how do I DRY this up? I looked at shared contexts, but then I can't access my models. I could create a helper method and return an array/hash of objects, but it seems like there should be something built in to do this in an elegant way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out shared context:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-context

```
# /spec/support/shared_stuff.rb

shared_context "shared stuff" do
  let(:model_1) { FactoryGirl.create(:model_1) }
  let(:model_2) { FactoryGirl.create(:model_2) }
end
```

then in your spec:

```
describe "group that includes a shared context using 'include_context'" do
  include_context "shared stuff"

  # ...
end
```

Comment: I didn't know about the let command before. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use FactoryGirl's callback feature:

In your tests, you might do something like

```
describe 'something else' do
  it 'another test' do
    a_model = FactoryGirl.create(:a_model_with_another)
    #different code using a_model and another 
  end
end
```

Your Factory definition would be something like:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :a_model do

    factory :a_model_with_another do
      after(:create) {FactoryGirl.create(:another)}
    end
  end
end
```

You can find more details in the [docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#callbacks)